# Show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied at the origin but $f$ is not analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

Let 
$$f(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^{3}(1+i)-y^{3}(1+i)}{x^{2}+y^{2}}, & z\neq0\\0, & z=0
\end{cases}$$

I want to show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied at the origin but $f$ is not analytic. Please, how can I show this?
 I already know that the satisfaction of Cauchy-Riemann equations is the neccessary and sufficient condition for a function $f(z)$ to be analytic, then how is it possible to show that the fuction satisfies C-R equations at the origin but not analytic?

Comment: Doesn't $u(x, y) = v(x, y) = -u(y, x)$?  This would mean that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$.  So this would satisfy the second CR equation, but not the first.

Comment: What does this means If it satisfy one condition of C-R equation?

Answer (score 5):

> the satisfaction of Cauchy-Riemann equations is the necessary and sufficient condition for a function $f$ to be analytic

More precisely, the satisfaction of  Cauchy-Riemann equations **on an open set** is the necessary and sufficient condition for  $f$ to be analytic on that set.

The exercise is meant to demonstrate that C-R equations can hold **at one point** without the function being analytic at that point. You can check that all partials are zero at the origin,  so C-R equations are satisfied there. But they do not hold anywhere else.

If $f$ were analytic at $0$, it would (by definition) be represented by a power series in a **neighborhood** of $0$. But then C-R equations would hold in that neighborhood, which is not the case.